# Debug\Release и вызов delete

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ассемблер, дизассемблирование

Добрый день. Есть примерно такой код:

```
typedef std::map< unsigned int, Signal > SMap;
void thread_proc( )
{
try
{
        for( ; ; )
        {
            std::vector< SMap > signals; ///
            {
                boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_mutex );

                m_signalMaps.swap( signals );
            }


            BOOST_FOREACH( const auto& signal, signals )
                HandleSignalMaps( signal );
        } //Далее будет указан дизассемблированный код этого участка программы
}
catch( const boost::thread_interrupted& )
{
}
```

}

Пытаюсь смотреть его дизассемблированный вариант. Заметил следующий факт:
В Release и Debug код различается вызовом delete.

**Release:**

```
rcx,qword ptr [signals]  
000007FECFF71902  test        rcx,rcx  
000007FECFF71905  je          thread_proc+1CBh (07FECFF7191Bh)  
000007FECFF71907  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rsp+30h]  
000007FECFF7190C  call        std::vector<std::map<unsigned int,Signal,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,Signal> > >,std::allocator<std::map<unsigned int,Signal,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,Signal> > > > >::_Destroy (07FECFF71BF0h)  
000007FECFF71911  mov         rcx,qword ptr [signals]  
000007FECFF71916  call        operator delete (07FECFFBCDF4h)  // Вот этот оператор
000007FECFF7191B  mov         qword ptr [signals],r12  
000007FECFF71920  mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],r12  
000007FECFF71925  mov         qword ptr [rsp+38h],r12  
000007FECFF7192A  jmp         thread_proc+40h (07FECFF71790h)
```

**Debug:**

```
000007FECCC44A09  lea         rcx,[rsp+28h]  
000007FECCC44A0E  call        std::vector<std::map<unsigned int,Signal,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,Signal> > >,std::allocator<std::map<unsigned int,Signal,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,Signal> > > > >::~vector<std::map<unsigned int,Signal,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,Signal> > >,std::allocator<std::map<unsigned int,Signal,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,Signal> > > > > (07FECCB06226h)  
000007FECCC44A13  jmp         thread_proc+30h (07FECCC44510h)
```

Я, так понимаю, в релизе delete пытается удалить локальный вектор 'signals'. Но почему этого нет в Debug? И разве локальные переменные удаляются вызовом delete? Я предполагал, что будет вызов 'pop', т.к. память должна была быть выделена на стеке. Объясните, пожалуйста, где я ошибаюсь в рассуждениях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен в правильности.

Внутренний массив у `vector` не может быть выделен целиком не стеке, т.к. ограничение на размер переменной в стеке порядка 4MB (по умолчанию), а вектор может быть и 100MB и больше. 
Т.е. по сути `vector` это обёртка над динамическим массивом. При удалении объекта класса `vector` мы должны в деструкторе удалить его динамический массив. Дальше компилятор может инлайнить вызов деструктора как хочет.

Попробуйте сделать минимальный пример работы с вектором и его удаления например такой:

```
void test() {
  vector<int> P;
  P.resize(10000);
}
```

Без оптимизации

```
test():
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $40, %rsp
    leaq    -48(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector()
    leaq    -48(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $10000, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::resize(unsigned long)
    leaq    -48(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector()
    jmp     .L4
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    leaq    -48(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector()
    movq    %rbx, %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _Unwind_Resume
```

Чётко виден конструктор и дестркутор

`-O2`:

```
test():
    subq    $8, %rsp
    movl    $40000, %edi
    call    operator new(unsigned long)
    leaq    40000(%rax), %rcx
    movq    %rax, %rdx
.L2:
    movl    $0, (%rdx)
    addq    $4, %rdx
    cmpq    %rcx, %rdx
    jne     .L2
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    addq    $8, %rsp
    jmp     operator delete(void*)
```

Вектор заменён на динамический массив (инлайнинг).

asm код генерировался тут https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Думаю в вашем случае в релизе компилятор сумел оптимизировать код.